# A variable's value is a variable

Tags: javascript

How would I refer to a variable(X) by using another variable(Y) that has the first variable(X) as its value?

Essentially, X = 1 is defined at the start of the document, and eventually Y=X. How can I take Y and tweak it so that, without directly calling X, I can change the value of X up or down?

The reason I don't want to call X directly is because this can happen hundreds of different times and it would be incredibly poor code to implement every instance.

For instance, Y could have a value of A, or B, or XCZ, or AASDFS... you get the idea. And all of these would themselves be variables whose value starts at 0 and can go up and down.

I can't do Y++ because Y is a string, I need to convert the string (the contents of Y) into the variable that has the exact same name as the contents of the string, then adjust the value of that.

Is there some way to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unless you are using objects, you can not do it with numbers.

Comment: Is there a way to handle this from an ends-justify-the-means perspective by somehow utilizing objects?

Comment: A variable in JavaScript is not a value: first, let this go.

Comment: `var obj = { count : 0 }; var x = obj; x.count++; console.log(obj.count);`